# Android data transfer between apps and website

Tags: javascript, android, web

I have build a website which provide a lot of data and based on some rules of company, I can't directly get the data from database for my app version. The only way to do it is to use a webview to show the previous website, but I want to get some data reference to the website for my app processing.

I would like to get an values call productID from the website and use it to save as a record into the mobile local database. This saving move will run in the Android app. Is there a way to do this?

It there a way to get data from the website? Is JavaScript possible for this case?

Comment: a simple answer to this is ... use webservices

Comment: @Kennett you can implement REST apis to access your data base resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few words to Google for you. Just look out for a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) for you Server (you can write it in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)) to give the data in JSON to your app.

Use GSON in your app to get the JSON object to a Java object. And keep in mind to do all network calls in a thread/async task. You can have a look at the Volley library provided by Google.

Have fun with your Project ;) Step by step, and you will get it!

[Tutorial](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.de/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html)

Comment: thank you for your reply:) but i am focusing on another question that is 'how to get website's data in mobile app?' since there are already a built website and the only data source is from website, i am not able to get the data directly by mysql and php and json:(

Comment: i am looking at REST api now, thank you for your kindly help, if i o have question again i will reply here, thx!!